# Angular9 application app selector html not loading with prod build

Tags: angular, angular9

I have migrated my angular application from angular8 to 9.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "visur",
  "version": "1.4.7-alpha.3",  
  "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.11",
    "@capacitor/android": "2.2.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.2.0",
    "@datorama/akita": "^4.23.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-forms-manager": "^3.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "5.2.0",
    "@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "9.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.10.2",
    "ajv": "6.12.2",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.3.2",
    "angular-tree-component": "8.5.6",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.21",
    "bpmn-js": "7.2.0",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.33.2",
    "brace": "0.11.1",
    "bs-platform": "^7.3.2",
    "capacitor-sqlite": "~2.1.0-7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "~6.0.2",
    "countries-and-timezones": "^2.2.0",
    "countrycitystatejson": "^0.2.15",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "d3-tip": "^0.9.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "echarts": "^4.8.0",
    "electron-dl": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.0.6",
    "electron-updater": "4.1.2",
    "electron-window-state": "5.0.3",
    "electron-window-state-manager": "0.3.2",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "getusermedia": "^2.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "idb": "^5.0.4",
    "immer": "^7.0.0",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.3.1",
    "ionic-long-press": "2.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-logic-js": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.2",
    "knex": "^0.21.1",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.10.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.10.0",
    "mobx-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.0",
    "ng2-popover": "0.0.14",
    "ng2draggable": "1.3.2",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-scroll-event": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "ngx-web-worker": "^8.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^7.0.0",
    "observable-webworker": "^3.2.4",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rebuild": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
    "timespan": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "videogular2": "^7.0.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "zoomdata-client": "^5.8.0-6.20200609030059.b826d893.release"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.1.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.2.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.11",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "2.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^9.1.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jsonpath": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.51.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.6",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/sqlite3": "3.1.6",
    "@types/three": "^0.103.2",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.2",
    "electron": "^8.3.1",
    "electron-builder": "21.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
    "electron-reload": "1.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "http-server-legacy": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "karma": "5.0.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.15.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "npm-upgrade": "^2.0.3",
    "npx": "10.2.2",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "wait-on": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "stream": false,
    "zlib": false
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }

}
```

**tsconfig-app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
],
  "exclude": [
    "ClientApp/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

with `ng serve` working,but with ng build --prod not working and in browser look like app html is not getting load,blank page displaying.And also not getting any browser console error and warning.

browser inspect element [image]

**#Updated: browser console**

**normal browser:**[image]

**Incognito**[image]

Comment: What do you have in the console?

Comment: @david can you please see I have updated the question with browser console